# Simply slider in JS not working

Tags: javascript, slider

Im going to create simply slider in JavaScript (without jquery).
I have .xhtml page with unordered list:

```
<ul>
        <li class="slider"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="asd" width="600px" height="400px" /></li>
        <li class="slider"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="asd" width="600px" height="400px" /></li>
        <li class="slider"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="asd" width="600px" height="400px" /></li>
        <li class="slider"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="asd" width="600px" height="400px" /></li>
        <li class="slider"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="asd" width="600px" height="400px" /></li>
        <li class="slider"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="asd" width="600px" height="400px" /></li>
        <li class="slider"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="asd" width="600px" height="400px" /></li>
</ul>
```

It's my script:

```
var s = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
function hide() 
{
    for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) 
    {
      s[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

var i = 0;
function sw() 
{
   hide();
   s[i].style.display = "block";  
   i++;
   if (i >= s.length) i = 0; 
}
hide();
sw();
setInterval(sw, 1000);
```

Log.console show me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.

Comment: Where in your HTML are you adding your JS?

Comment: In external file main.js. Its XHTML

Comment: But where is your script tag? Is it in the head? The bottom of the body? Somewhere in between?

Comment: Between tag head: <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>

Comment: I add <script> after tag </body> and now its work. Why? ;)

Comment: Refer to my answer. In short, the DOM wasn't ready. You have to wait until your elements are actually processed and put together before trying to grab them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to grab all of your elements before they're loaded. Move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of the `<body>`. That way, your elements will have been loaded into the DOM.

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="slider"></li>
    ...
  </ul>
  <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>
```